# When I put EnableViewState="true" in the page decliration on one of my pages, Request.UserAgent will be null

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am trying to use ViewState so I can put things like success messages in labels on my page when a user is created. In order to do this apparently I need to enable viewstates. When I do this I am no longer able to detect the users useragent SOMETIMES, it seems like every other time I run the app it works and other times its null.

CreateNewUser.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Create a New User" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateNewUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="STAT2.Admin.CreateNewUser" EnableViewState="true"%>
```

Site.Master.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE 8.0") // NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION (UserAgent == null!)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The *default* is `true`. Something else is causing your problem.

Comment: Do you have browser extensions that would clear / mask / hide your User Agent?